# Real time messages using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
window.setInterval(function(){

  $.post ('<?php echo  base_url(); ?>ClientCont/List_Files/fetchmessage',
    {
      id:folderid
    },
    function(data){
      console.log(data);
      if(data.length > 0){

        var a;
        for(a = 0; a < data.length; a++){
          $('#previouscomment').append("<div id  = 'dateconvo' style = 'margin-top:20px;text-align:center;color:#D3D3D3'>" + data[a]['date_entry'] + "</div><br>" + 
          "<input id = 'oldid' type  = 'hidden' value = " + data[a]['comment_id'] + ">" +
          "<div id  = 'usernamemessage' style = 'color:#D3D3D3'>" + atob(data[a]['name_user']) + "</div>" + 
          "<div id = 'messageme' style = 'margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;border-radius: .4em;background-color: #4CAF50!important; border-radius: 5px;box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2; display: inline-block;padding: 10px 18px;position: relative;vertical-align: top;color:#FFFFFF'>" +
          data[a]['message']) + "\n";
        }

      }else{

        $('#previouscomment').append("<div align = 'center' style  = 'margin-top:30px;color:#D3D3D3'><img src = '<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/nocommentyet.png' align  = 'middle' style = 'height:100px;width:100px;'/>" + "<br>NO COMMENT TO DISPLAY</div>");

      }
     $("#previouscomment").animate({ scrollTop: "2000000000000px" }, "fast"); 
    },
    'json'
  );
},1000);
```

I have the following code, but unfortunately every minute it appends the messages... Even messages that were previously appended.

I just want to ask how to avoid the  redunduncy of messages at each execution of the code. It should only fetch new messages.

Comment: Could you please add sample data logged to console in the question? Probably will give us a clear picture of how sample data looks.

Comment: The interval loop is running every second... Not every minute, by the way. That is pretty bandwidth consuming. I would look into [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) to send any new message from the server instead of using `.post()` every second.

Answer (score 0):

in your code, you define the loop which is reading all the objects in response and there is no unique id for each of the appended elements so we are going to assign each appended div with a unique id which we will get from the response  in your case we will use `comment_id` and before append we will check if this element has existed or not

```
            window.setInterval(function() {

            $.post('<?php echo  base_url(); ?>ClientCont/List_Files/fetchmessage', {
                id: folderid
            }, function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.length > 0) {

                    var a;
                    for (a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
                        if ($('#dateconvo' + data[a]['comment_id']).length == 0) {
                            $('#previouscomment').append("<div id  = 'dateconvo" + data[a]['comment_id'] + "' style = 'margin-top:20px;text-align:center;color:#D3D3D3'>" + data[a]['date_entry'] + "</div><br>" +
                                "<input id = 'oldid' type  = 'hidden' value = " + data[a]['comment_id'] + ">" +
                                "<div id  = 'usernamemessage' style = 'color:#D3D3D3'>" + atob(data[a]['name_user']) + "</div>" +
                                "<div id = 'messageme' style = 'margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;border-radius: .4em;background-color: #4CAF50!important; border-radius: 5px;box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2; display: inline-block;padding: 10px 18px;position: relative;vertical-align: top;color:#FFFFFF'>" +
                                data[a]['message']) + "\n";
                        }
                    }

                } else {

                    $('#previouscomment').append("<div align = 'center' style  = 'margin-top:30px;color:#D3D3D3'><img src = '<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/nocommentyet.png' align  = 'middle' style = 'height:100px;width:100px;'/>" + "<br>NO COMMENT TO DISPLAY</div>");

                }
                $("#previouscomment").animate({
                    scrollTop: "2000000000000px"
                }, "fast");
            }, 'json');
        }, 1000);
```

---